# Size Inspector missing options in xcode 11.3.1

Tags: swift, xcode, autolayout, storyboard, constraints

I am trying to replicate a GitHub project to practise using constraints. The new project I've created displays the following in the size inspector:
[image: my Xcode Size Inspector]

The GitHub Project displays the following in the size inspector. The section below 'Layout Margins' is missing from my project. How can I get this missing section to display?

[image: GitHub project]

Comment: Once you add the constraints, the section below the layout margins will be visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add any constraint to the view and that section will be visible as per the GitHub project displays.